# How to get Array of Unique PIDs from CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo in Swift

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift3, nspredicate, core-foundation

I am trying to convert the following Objective-C method to **Swift 3**. The **goal** is to obtain an array of *unique* process identifiers (`kCGWindowOwnerPID`) for all "onscreen" window elements in layer 0, excluding desktop elements.

My Obj-C method uses `NSSet` to remove duplicate PIDs from an `NSArray` that is filtered using an `NSPredicate`

```
+ (NSArray*)filteredProcessIndentifiers
{
    pid_t myPid = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier];

    NSArray *windowList = (id)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly
                                 | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements,
                                   kCGNullWindowID);

    NSArray *uniquePidArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:[
                    [(id)windowList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(kCGWindowLayer == 0 && kCGWindowOwnerPID != %d)", myPid]]
                    valueForKey:@"kCGWindowOwnerPID"]]
                    allObjects];

    if (windowList) {
        CFRelease(windowList);
    }

    return uniquePidArray;
}
```

This **Swift 3** example works to get a filtered array of elements (in layer 0 and not `myPid`), however this test contains *all* `keys`, *and* duplicate PIDs:

```
/// - returns: Array of WindowInfo dictionaries.
func windowListFiltered() throws -> [AnyObject] {
    var windowListArray: CFArray?
    let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.excludeDesktopElements, CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenOnly)
    let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(kCGWindowLayer == 0 && kCGWindowOwnerPID != %d)", getpid())

    windowListArray = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID)
    let filtered = (windowListArray as NSArray?)?.filtered(using: filterPredicate)
    return (filtered as [AnyObject]?)!
}
```

The `windowListFiltered()` method result produces:

```
[{
    kCGWindowAlpha = 1;
    kCGWindowBounds =     {
        Height = 436;
        Width = 770;
        X = 525;
        Y = 313;
    };
    kCGWindowIsOnscreen = 1;
    kCGWindowLayer = 0;
    kCGWindowMemoryUsage = 1072;
    kCGWindowName = Debug;
    kCGWindowNumber = 213;
    kCGWindowOwnerName = Finder;
    kCGWindowOwnerPID = 453;
    kCGWindowSharingState = 1;
    kCGWindowStoreType = 1;
}, {
    kCGWindowAlpha = 1;
    kCGWindowBounds =     {
        Height = 537;
        Width = 380;
        X = 61;
        Y = 354;
    };
    kCGWindowIsOnscreen = 1;
    kCGWindowLayer = 0;
    kCGWindowMemoryUsage = 1072;
    kCGWindowName = Documents;
    kCGWindowNumber = 3416;
    kCGWindowOwnerName = Finder;
    kCGWindowOwnerPID = 453;
    kCGWindowSharingState = 1;
    kCGWindowStoreType = 1;
}, {
    kCGWindowAlpha = 1;
    kCGWindowBounds =     {
        Height = 22;
        Width = 1414;
        X = 118;
        Y = 28;
    };
    kCGWindowIsOnscreen = 1;
    kCGWindowLayer = 0;
    kCGWindowMemoryUsage = 128208;
    kCGWindowName = "swift3 - Cannot subscript a value of type [[String:Any]] with an index of type 'String' - Swift 3 - Stack Overflow";
    kCGWindowNumber = 7798;
    kCGWindowOwnerName = WindowMizer;
    kCGWindowOwnerPID = 495;
    kCGWindowSharingState = 1;
    kCGWindowStoreType = 2;
}]
```

What I need is an Array like:

```
[453,495]
```

I have been able to get part-way there, but I am unable to pull an array of PIDs from the `filtered` array. This attempt iterates through one array to build a second array, which does work, but there are still duplicate PIDs - which I can eliminate, but I am trying to find the best way to accomplish the original **Goal**.

```
func filteredProcessIndentifiers() throws -> [Int] {
    var processIds:[Int] = []
    var windowListArray: CFArray?
    let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.excludeDesktopElements, CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenOnly)
    let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(kCGWindowLayer == 0 && kCGWindowOwnerPID != %d)", getpid())
    windowListArray = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID)
    let filtered = (windowListArray as NSArray?)?.filtered(using: filterPredicate) as? [[ String : Any]]

    for dict in filtered! {
        processIds.append((dict["kCGWindowOwnerPID"] as! Int))
    }

    return processIds
}
```

In simplest terms, considering I have the `filtered` array, I tried to return:

```
filtered["kCGWindowOwnerPID"]
```

which won't compile due to error: "Type 'NSArray?' has no subscript members"

I am hoping to create something a little more succinct like the beautiful Objective-C example :-). I'll try again tonight and concentrate on using a Swift3 equivalent to `NSSet` in order to eliminate duplicates.

Any insight on the best way to obtain an array of *unique* process identifiers from `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop inside the function `filteredProcessIndentifiers` change it to this:

```
for diction in filtered! {
    let test = diction as? Dictionary<String,Any>
    if let item = test{
         print("testa: \(String(describing: item["kCGWindowOwnerPID"]))")
    }
}
```

Thank you. I've been trying to figure this out for almost two days and coming across your question gave me this idea and it worked! So thank you.